# Запрос вставки в БД не производит запись

Tags: mysql, python

Есть MySQL на Amazon RDS.

Есть тестовая таблица из двух столбцов `(ID - INT, Event - Text)`

Подключился к ней, посылаю запрос вида:

```
SELECT * FROM Test WHERE ID=1
```

все работает на ура, ответ получаю.

Отсылаю запрос типа:

```
INSERT INTO Test VALUES (2, "Text")
```

все хорошо - получаю пустой ответ, но запись не производится. В чём проблема?

Написал на C# консольную программу для управления БД - там все работает, данные для входа те же.

```
import MySQLdb

db = MySQLdb.connect(host="host",    # your host, usually localhost
                     user="user",         # your username
                     passwd="pass",  # your password
                     db="db")        # name of the data base

# you must create a Cursor object. It will let
#  you execute all the queries you need
cur = db.cursor()

# Use all the SQL you like
sql = 'INSERT INTO Test VALUES (3,"Example")'
cur.execute(sql)

# print all the first cell of all the rows
for row in cur.fetchall():
    print (row)

db.close()
```

Comment: Предоставьте код отсылки запроса `insert` в питоне

Comment: Добавил в вопрос.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Первое, что бросается в глаза - `cur.fetchall()` "вытягивает" записи, возвращенные *последним* запросом. В вашем случае последний запрос - это `INSERT`, который не возвращает записей.

Кроме этого попробуйте добавить `db.commit()` после `cur.execute(sql)`.

Comment: db.commit() помогло. Спасибо, добрый человек)